# I am confused on how to solve a question by using burnside's lemma:

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to color the ten balls of a triangular array that is free to rotate using 2 colors?

The triangular array is arranged such that a single ball is in the apex [first row]; the next row is composed of two balls; the third row is three balls, and the fourth row is four balls.  This is for a homework assignment and I am relatively new to mathematics and this class.  The textbook is not very helpful in terms of explaining how to solve such a problem.

Answer (score 2):

In order to apply Burnside's lemma we need a group to be acting on a set.  Here the group will be the cyclic group of order 3.  The set will be the set of $oriented$ two-colorings of the balls.   Where by oriented I mean we distinguish between two different colorings that are rotations of one another. The action will be induced from the action of the group on the balls. The orbits of this action will be the set of colorings where we don't distinguish between rotations.

The identity element fixes all $2^{10}$ oriented colorings. The two rotations each fix $2^4$ oriented colorings, the $4$ comes from the $4$ orbits of these rotations on the balls themselves.

Burnsides lemma tells us that the number of orbits is $\frac{1}{3}(2^{10}+2^4 +2^4) =352$

Answer (score 2):

We  can actually  solve a  more  general question  where the  triangle
consists of $n$ levels and $\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)$ vertices. In order to
apply Burnside we  compute the cycle index $Z(G)$ of  the group $G$ of
the vertices  under rotation. There are only  three permutations here,
the   identity   and   two   rotations.   The   identity   contributes
$a_1^{\frac{1}{2}  n (n+1)}.$ The  two rotations  partition everything
into  three-cycles  except  for  the  center vertex  when  $n$  is  is
congruent to one modulo three. Therefore for $n=3m+1$ we get the cycle
index

$$Z(G) = \frac{1}{3} 
\left(a_1^{\frac{1}{2} n  (n+1)} + 
2 a_1 a_3^{\frac{1}{6} (n-1) (n+2)}\right)$$
and for $n=3m+2$ and $n=3m+3$ we get
$$Z(H) = \frac{1}{3} 
\left(a_1^{\frac{1}{2} n  (n+1)} + 
2 a_3^{\frac{1}{6} n (n+1)}\right).$$

There are two colors and the  colorings must be constant on the cycles
so when $n=3m+1$ we get for the count $Q_n$ of two-colorings
$$Q_n =  \frac{1}{3} 
\left(2^{\frac{1}{2} n  (n+1)} + 
2 \times 2 \times 2^{\frac{1}{6} (n-1) (n+2)}\right)
=  \frac{1}{3} 
\left(2^{\frac{1}{2} n  (n+1)} + 
2^{2+\frac{1}{6} (n-1) (n+2)}\right)$$
and for $n=3m+2$ or $n=3m+3$ we get
$$Q_n = \frac{1}{3} 
\left(2^{\frac{1}{2} n  (n+1)} + 
2 \times 2^{\frac{1}{6} n (n+1)}\right)
= \frac{1}{3} 
\left(2^{\frac{1}{2} n  (n+1)} + 
2^{1+\frac{1}{6} n (n+1)}\right).$$

This is the following sequence:
$$2, 4, 24, 352, 10944, 699136, 89479168, 22906494976, 
11728124051456 ,\ldots $$

**Verification.**   We  can   verify  these   formulas   using  direct
enumeration.   This is  based  on the  observation  that the  $\lfloor
(n+2)/3 \rfloor$  nested triangles that the  figure is made  up of are
only fixed  by the three permutations  if they have the  same color at
the corners   and  one of  $2^{p-2}$ oriented sequences  that  are  in
agreement on the three sides (of length $p$).

This gives for $n=3m+1$ the result
$$Q_n = 2 \times
\prod_{q=1}^m 2 \times  2^{3q+1-2}
+ \frac{1}{3} 
\left(2^{\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)}
- 2 \times
\prod_{q=1}^m 2 \times  2^{3q+1-2} \right)
\\ = 
\frac{2}{3} 2^{m+1} \times 2^{\sum_{q=1}^m 3q-1}
+ \frac{1}{3} 
\times 2^{\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)}
\\ = \frac{1}{3}
\left(2^{3/2\times m^2+3/2\times m+2}+2^{\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)}\right).$$
This is easily seen to match the formula from above.

For $n=3m+2$ we get the result
$$Q_n =
\prod_{q=0}^m 2 \times 2^{3q+2-2}
+ \frac{1}{3}
\left(2^{\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)}
- \prod_{q=0}^m 2 \times 2^{3q+2-2} \right)
\\ = \frac{2}{3} 2^{m+1} 2^{\sum_{q=0}^m 3q}
+ \frac{1}{3} 
\times 2^{\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)}
\\ =
\frac{1}{3}
\left(2^{3/2\times m^2+5/2\times m+2} + 2^{\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)}\right)$$ 
This also matches the formula from above.

Finally we put $n=3m+3$ to get
$$Q_n =
\prod_{q=0}^m 2 \times 2^{3q+3-2}
+ \frac{1}{3}
\left(2^{\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)}
- \prod_{q=0}^m 2 \times 2^{3q+3-2} \right)
\\ = \frac{2}{3} 2^{m+1} 2^{\sum_{q=0}^m 3q+1}
+ \frac{1}{3} 
\times 2^{\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)}
\\ =
\frac{1}{3}
\left(2^{3/2\times m^2+7/2\times m+3} + 2^{\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)}\right)$$ 
once again a match.